# mysql help - writing a query to show productsthat are in more than one category, as long as they are in a specific category

Tags: mysql

having a bit of a prob with this, though I'm sure it's simple!

I have a table where product IDs are matched to category ID, these are the only 2 fields in the table.

I want to see whether all the products in the cards category (ID=100) are in any other categories, or just that one.  I tried a few things but can't figure the query out.

```
SELECT products_id, count(categories_id) as cats_in FROM `products_to_categories` WHERE categories_id = 100 group by products_id
```

This always shows 1 for the cats_in column, even though I know some of them are in more than one category as I have checked.  I know I'm useless with grouping and counting, so help to understand this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select distinct 
 pc.cat_id
from
 product_category pc
inner join
(
 select prod_id from product_category where cat_id = 100
) cards on cards.prod_id = pc.prod_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added a group and select prod_id too and it's just what I needed!  I have a lot to learn about mysql so thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Think, this would help you:

```
select product_id, count(distinct category_id), category_id
from products_to_categories
group by product_id
having category_id = 100
  and count(distinct category_id) > 1;
```

Comment: That's better, but doesn't seem to return all of them, it's finding only some of them.  Thank you for your reply though :)

Comment: If you'll provide structure of table and data from it, i'll think some more. =)

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but we have the answer now.  You can rest!

Answer (score 0):

The typical structure is like this and it seems this mirrors what you have?

```
PRODUCTS
id  integer primary key
productname varchar


CATEGORIES
id integer primary key
categoryname  varchar


PRODUCTCATEGORIES
id integer primary key
productid integer
categorid integer    
[unique index on (productid, categoryid)  ... or you could make this dyad the primary key]
```

You could do this:

```
select productid from PRODUCTCATEGORIES
where categoryid <> 100 and productid in
(
select productid from PRODUCTCATEGORIES
where categoryid = 100
)
```

The subquery finds the productids of products in category 100. The outer query finds the subset of those products that are also in another category.

Comment: Thanks very much, this also works well!  I guess there are many ways to tackle, it's great to have help when learning.  Thanks again.